# populate a dictionary using linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary

I have the following empty Dictionary

```
Dictionary<Guid, string> appTypeMap = new Dictionary<Guid, string>();
```

and the following list:

```
List<ApplicationType> allApplicationTypes = _applicationTypeService.GetAll()
```

Application type is described as follows:

```
public class ApplicationType
{
   public Guid id {get; set;}
   public String name {get; set;}
}
```

I want to populate the dictionary using LINQ.
How do I do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

```
appTypeMap = allApplicationTypes.ToDictionary(x => x.id, x => x.name);
```

However, it will create a new dictionary, not fill yours.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
appTypeMap = _applicationTypeService.GetAll().Select(o => new DictionaryEntry{
  Key = o.id,
  Value = o.name
}).ToList();
```

Not sure if you need a .ToList() on the end....

Comment: Should at least leave a comment for a negative. This is a valid answer and shows an alternative method.

Comment: i didn't downvote, but the compiler gives the "Cannot implicitly convert.." error with this code.

Comment: interesting, I had wondered if the .ToList() was needed. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Sorry, but this will work only if you are expecting a list of `DictionaryEntry`s, but not a dictionary...