# Build Dictionary with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary, .net-core

Let's say we have a variable 'data' which is a list of Id's and Child Id's:

```
var data = new List<Data>
{
    new()
    {
        Id = 1,
        ChildIds = new List<int> {123, 234, 345}
    },
    new()
    {
        Id = 1,
        ChildIds = new List<int> {123, 234, 345}
    },
    new()
    {
        Id = 2,
        ChildIds = new List<int> {678, 789}
    },
};
```

I would like to have a dictionary with ChildId's and the related Id's. If the ChildId is already in the dictionary, it should overwrite with the new Id.

Currently I have this code:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
foreach (var dataItem in data)
{
    foreach (var child in dataItem.ChildIds)
    {
        dict[child] = dataItem.Id;
    }
}
```

This works fine, but I don't like the fact that I am using two loops. I prefer to use Linq ToDictionary to build up the dictionary in a Functional way.
What is the best way to build up the dictionary by using Linq?

Why? I prefer functional code over mutating a state. Besides that, I was just curious how to build up the dictionary by using Linq ;-)

Comment: Are you looking for `SelectMany`?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590723/flatten-list-in-linq

Comment: `This works fine, but I don't like the fact that I am using two loops. I prefer to use Linq ToDictionary to build up the dictionary in a Functional way` why, what's wrong with your approach? How are you going to use this data? Have you tried Linq, if not, give it a go and let us know if you have any specific issues. If you have, post the related Linq and we can further help.

Comment: You're approach is fine, the only thing LINQ would do is abstract away what you're already doing. Other than additional error correction I don't see any issue wrong with your implementation.

Comment: This code works, but I prefer functional code over mutating a state. Besides that, I was just curious how to build up the dictionary by using Linq ;-)

Comment: @zaggler Exactly the same, however I like the conciseness and readability of Linq.

Comment: @Rogier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324282/populate-a-dictionary-using-linq https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549103/linq-convert-list-to-dictionary-with-value-as-list/3549164

Comment: Group the items by id and then use the last of each group to build the dictionary with ToDictionary

Comment: Make sure you're covering your code with proper test inputs. The provided dataset in your question is misleading and caused some mistakes in the answers below. Try adding `123` next to `678` to make your dataset more reliable for verification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case your foreach appproach is both, readable and efficient. So even if i'm a fan of LINQ i would use that. The loop has the bonus that you can debug it easily or add logging if necessary(for example invalid id's).

However, if you want to use LINQ i would probably use [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-5.0) and [`ToLookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup?view=net-5.0). The former is used to flatten child collections like this `ChildIds` and the latter is used to create a collection which is very similar to your dictionary. But one difference is that it allows duplicate keys, you get multiple values in that case:

```
ILookup<int, int> idLookup = data
    .SelectMany(d => d.ChildIds.Select(c => (Id:d.Id, ChildId:c)))
    .ToLookup(x => x.ChildId, x => x.Id);
```

Now you have already everything you needed since it can be used like a dictionary with same lookup performance. If you wanted to create that dictionary anyway, you can use:

```
Dictionary<int, int> dict = idLookup.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.First());
```

If you want to override duplicates with the new Id, as mentioned, simply use `Last()`.

.NET-Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mUBZPi

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer. All of the other answers are either "wrong" or not as good.

Answer (score 3):

The SelectMany linq operator actually has a few less known overloads. One of these has a result collector which is a perfect use case for your scenario.

Following is an example code snippet to turn that into a dictionary. Note that I had to use the Distinct, since you had 2 id's with value 1 which had some duplicated child id's which would pose problems for a dictionary.

```
void Main()
{
    // Get the data
    var list = GetData();
    
    // Turn it into a dictionary
    var dict = list
        .SelectMany(d => d.ChildIds, (data, childId) => new {data.Id, childId})
        .Distinct()
        .ToDictionary(x => x.childId, x => x.Id);

    // show the content of the dictionary
    dict.Keys
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(k => Console.WriteLine($"{k} {dict[k]}"));
}

public List<Data> GetData()
{
    return 
        new List<Data>
        {
            new Data
            {
                Id = 1,
                ChildIds = new List<int> {123, 234, 345}
            },
            new Data
            {
                Id = 1,
                ChildIds = new List<int> {123, 234, 345}
            },
            new Data
            {
                Id = 2,
                ChildIds = new List<int> {678, 789}
            },
        };
}

public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<int> ChildIds { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is a wonderful answer. I was not aware of this overload in SelectMany.

Comment: This code throws exception if fed with a slightly different dataset. Just replace 678 with 123 in data.

Answer (score 2):

The approach is to create pairs of each combination of Id and ChildId, and build a dictionary of these:

```
        var list = new List<(int Id, int[] ChildIds)>()
        {
            (1, new []{10, 11}),
            (2, new []{11, 12})
        };

        var result = list
            .SelectMany(pair => pair.ChildIds.Select(childId => (childId, pair.Id)))
            .ToDictionary(p => p.childId, p => p.Id);
```

`ToDictionary` will throw if there are duplicate keys, to avoid this you can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10626380/12342238) and create your own ToDictionary:

```
    public static Dictionary<K, V> ToDictionaryOverWriting<TSource, K, V>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, K> keySelector,
        Func<TSource, V> valueSelector)
    {
        Dictionary<K, V> output = new Dictionary<K, V>();
        foreach (TSource item in source)
        {
            output[keySelector(item)] = valueSelector(item);
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

With LINQ you can achieve the result like this:

```cshapr
Dictionary<int, int> dict = (from item in data
                             from childId in item.ChildIds
                             select new { item.Id, childId}
                             ).Distinct()
                             .ToDictionary(kv => kv.childId, kv => kv.Id);
```

**Update:**

Fully compatible version with `foreach` loop would use `group by` with `Last()`, instead of `Distict()`:

```csharp
Dictionary<int, int> dict2 = (from item in data
                                from childId in item.ChildIds
                                group new { item.Id, childId } by childId into g
                                select g.Last()
                                ).ToDictionary(kv => kv.childId, kv => kv.Id);
```

As some already pointed out, depending on order of input elements does not feel "functional". LINQ expression becomes more convoluted then original `foreach` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, although I got the following exception:
`System.ArgumentException: 'An item with the same key has already been added.`

Comment: Given the requirement to overwrite if a child is already in the dictionary, this LINQ should probably do a GroupBy() followed by a Last() to pick the last from among the duplicates prior to building the dictionary.

Comment: @Rogier `Distinct()` was missing, because you have duplicated data.

Comment: This is wrong. Distinct does not work only on Keys here, it works on key value pairs which are always distinct values.

Comment: @Bizhan key-value pairs are not always distinct values. He has duplicates in the `Data`. for example `123-1`, 2 times. This code produces exactly the same `dict` as the original example. You should try it.

Comment: You're right, `Equals` compares the values in anonymous types. However your code still throws exception if you replace `678` with `123` in data

Comment: Another problem with your code is it detects (123-1) and (123-2) as two different items, which contradicts what OP wanted. (OP wants to have only the second item)

Comment: @Bizhan You mean, if you introduce extra value `2-123` in `data`, my first example would produce different result compared to `foreach` loop?

Comment: I didn't test your foreach loop. But the first snippet throws exception.

Comment: @Bizhan There is/was no `foreach` loop in my answer. Is 2nd example working for you or not?

Answer (score 1):

There is an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_SelectMany__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1___System_Func___0___1___2__) of `SelectMany` which not only flattens the collection but also allows you to have any form of result.

```
var all = data.SelectMany(
     data => data.ChildIds, //collectionSelector
     (data, ChildId) => new { data.Id, ChildId } //resultSelector 
);
```

Now if you want to transform `all` into a Dictionary, you have to remove the duplicate ChildIds first. You can use `GroupBy` as in below, and then pick the last item from each group (as you stated in your question you want to overwrite Ids as you go). The key of your dictionary should also be unique=`ChildId`:

```
var dict = all.GroupBy(x => x.ChildId)
              .Select(x => x.Last())
              .ToDictionary(x => x.ChildId, x => x.Id);
```

Or you can write a new class with `IEquatable<>` implemented and use it as the return type of resultSelector (instead of `new { data.Id, ChildId }`). Then write `all.Reverse().Distinct().ToDictionary(x => x.ChildId);` so it would detect duplicates based on your own implementation of `Equals` method. Reverse, because you said you want the last occurrence of the duplicates.